# Unable to create Home Directory for LDAP Login

Tags: ldap, home-directory

I have linked my server with LDAP for ssh login. I get the Following error while logging in using ssh.

> Could not chdir to home directory /home/ldap/sharukhk: No such file or directory

```
shahrukh@shahrukh:~/deploy$ ssh sharukhk@10.200.99.226
sharukhk@10.200.99.226's password: 
Last login: Tue Sep 29 14:28:10 2015 from 10.200.100.245
Could not chdir to home directory /home/ldap/sharukhk: No such file or directory
-bash-4.1$
```

I have tried the following method to auto create home directory while login but it does not work

```
session required pam_mkhomedir.so skel=/etc/skel/ umask=0077
```

Comment: Does /home/ldap exist?

Comment: i have created that directory manually

Comment: Which distro is this? For Debian/Ubuntu I had to add this line to common-session to get it to work.

Comment: it is centos os

Comment: while using pam_mkhomedir works fine, modern systems prefer `autodir` daemon. If you decide for autodir, you can leave pam untouched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be enabled using authconfig.

```
authconfig --enablemkhomedir --update
```

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Identity_Management_Guide/users.html#homedir-pammod

Answer (score 1):

same thing happens on on ubuntu 18.04 the fix is

```
# pam auth update
```

then select

```
[*] Create home directory on login
```

if you find out how to do this from the CLI please post me a comment

Answer (score 1):

IF SELinux is enabled or disabled then Need to config sshd pam module To creating home directory

```
vi /etc/pam.d/sshd
# pam_selinux.so close should be the first session rule
session required pam_mkhomedir.so skel=/etc/skel/ umask=0022
```